# Pass argument to django class-based view via url string

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I can't find out how to do this in the documentation.

I have a **view** that looks like:

```
from django_datatables_view.base_datatable_view import BaseDatatableView

class ListJson(BaseDatatableView):
    #...
```

Using class from https://bitbucket.org/pigletto/django-datatables-view

and my **urls**

```
url(r'^list/datatable/(?P<model_name>\w+)/$', login_required(views.ListJson.as_view()), name='list_json'),
```

I have tried accessing the model_name with self.kwargs['model_name'] in the view (to no avail)

Comment: Please show the code where you are attempting to access that value.

Comment: Which method you are overriding in `class ListJSON()` ?

Comment: @DanielRoseman https://github.com/adnmcq/djerp/blob/master/erp/views.py line 28 -I want to get a string (model name) from url for this view